# MSSQL: The configuration file '/var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf' failed to load (Ubuntu)

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I have an issue to install MSSQL on my Linux(Ubuntu 16.04) Server.

I have used the manual from Microsoft but I always fail on the same stage.
Actually, Docker is not an alternative due to Kernal issues.

After:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server
```

I'm supposed to do

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup.
```

This returns after answering all questions:

> sqlservr[8383]: sqlservr: The configuration file '/var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf' failed to load (error: The INI file could not be opened. Errno [2] Filename [mssql.conf]).

I can access the config file and it seems to be usable by the script as well.
My Linux skills are not good enough to resolve this issue.

To answer some questions that were raised:

1. I tried `sudo`
2. `cat` the file returns the content as expected

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have the path names right? That error doesn't match the line above. Also the error suggests the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @DavidG no, that does seem correct. Can you confirm the file trying to be accessed does exist? Does `cat /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf` return anything? You may need to proceed the command with `sudo`.

Comment: Cat returns the expected file content

root@h2668926:/# cat /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf
[sqlagent]
enabled = true

[EULA]
accepteula = Y

[language]
lcid = 1031

[filelocation]
defaultlogdir = /tmp/log


and i used sudo aswell with the same result

Comment: You say it returns as expected; what did it return?

Comment: That sounds like SQL Service has already been successfully configured.

Comment: Actually i can run the server itself but whenever I try to use the service it complains about the configuration file '/var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf' failed to load

Answer (score 2):

Try running mssql server as root first (stop the service, run it as root, with `/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr`) and see if it works that way. If it does, stop the mssql server and fix the ownership of the mssql dir with `sudo chown -R  mssql:mssql /var/opt/mssql`). More info on [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185045/sql-server-on-linux-hangs-on-initial-startup-no-errors-and-no-new-updated-er).